# openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: A session is either terminated or not started

Tags: android, selenium, appium-android

I'm using selenium + maven + cucumber + testng + appium for mobile ui test. Also I'm running this cases on the real device. But app's launching two times;

```
Mar 03, 2020 5:56:11 PM io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1 lambda$0
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Mar 03, 2020 5:56:37 PM io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1 lambda$0
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
```

And then i see the following error message;

```
Scenario: [1.0] Check Incoming Payment Types [90m# src/test/resources/features/Android/Payment.feature:6[0m
    [31mGiven [0m[31modeal app is launched[0m                [90m# PaymentFlow.launchedOdealApp()[0m
      [31morg.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: A session is either terminated or not started
      Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
      System info: host: 'admins-Mac-mini.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:14b1:249d:6e8e:379f%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.15.3', java.version: '1.8.0_231'
      Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
      Capabilities {app: /Users/busekaya/Desktop/app..., appActivity: com.telera.merchant.splash...., appPackage: com.telera.merchant.stage.d..., automationName: UiAutomator2, clearSystemFiles: false, databaseEnabled: false, desired: {app: /Users/busekaya/Desktop/app..., appActivity: com.telera.merchant.splash...., appPackage: com.telera.merchant.stage.d..., automationName: UiAutomator2, clearSystemFiles: false, deviceName: TestDevice-1, noReset: true, platformName: android, platformVersion: 7.1.1, udid: ZH33D2543D}, deviceApiLevel: 25, deviceManufacturer: motorola, deviceModel: Moto E (4) Plus, deviceName: ZH33D2543D, deviceScreenDensity: 320, deviceScreenSize: 720x1280, deviceUDID: ZH33D2543D, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: false, networkConnectionEnabled: true, noReset: true, pixelRatio: 2, platform: LINUX, platformName: Android, platformVersion: 7.1.1, statBarHeight: 48, takesScreenshot: true, udid: ZH33D2543D, viewportRect: {height: 1136, left: 0, top: 48, width: 720}, warnings: {}, webStorageEnabled: false}
      Session ID: 9b91b01c-08bd-4b7a-a65e-4e09e5a7fcf5
      *** Element info: {Using=id, value=login}
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
        at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:239)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
        at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:41)
        at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
        at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:323)
        at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElement(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:61)
        at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElement(AppiumDriver.java:1)
        at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.findElement(AndroidDriver.java:1)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementById(RemoteWebDriver.java:372)
        at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElementById(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:69)
        at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElementById(AppiumDriver.java:1)
        at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.findElementById(AndroidDriver.java:1)
        at org.openqa.selenium.By$ById.findElement(By.java:188)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:315)
        at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElement(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:57)
        at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElement(AppiumDriver.java:1)
        at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.findElement(AndroidDriver.java:1)
        at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$7.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:205)
        at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$7.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:201)
        at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$22.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:641)
        at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$22.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:638)
        at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:249)
        at com.odealMobile.PaymentFlow.launchedOdealApp(PaymentFlow.java:44)
        at ✽.Given odeal app is launched(src/test/resources/features/Android/Payment.feature:7)
      [0m
    [36mWhen [0m[36muser log in to Odeal successfully[0m     [90m# PaymentFlow.loginTheApp()[0m
    [36mAnd [0m[36mClicks on New Payment button[0m           [90m# PaymentFlow.clickNewPayment()[0m
    [36mAnd [0m[36mEnter Price to Opened Page[0m             [90m# PaymentFlow.enterPrice()[0m
    [36mAnd [0m[36mClicks on Get Paid button[0m              [90m# PaymentFlow.clickPaidButton()[0m
    [36mThen [0m[36mAll Payment Types will be Appeared[0m    [90m# PaymentFlow.checkPaymentTypes()[0m

[31mFailed scenarios:[0m
[31msrc/test/resources/features/Android/Payment.feature:6 [0m# Scenario: [1.0] Check Incoming Payment Types

1 Scenarios ([31m1 failed[0m)
6 Steps ([31m1 failed[0m, [36m5 skipped[0m)
0m54.617s

org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: A session is either terminated or not started
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'admins-Mac-mini.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:14b1:249d:6e8e:379f%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.15.3', java.version: '1.8.0_231'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Capabilities {app: /Users/busekaya/Desktop/app..., appActivity: com.telera.merchant.splash...., appPackage: com.telera.merchant.stage.d..., automationName: UiAutomator2, clearSystemFiles: false, databaseEnabled: false, desired: {app: /Users/busekaya/Desktop/app..., appActivity: com.telera.merchant.splash...., appPackage: com.telera.merchant.stage.d..., automationName: UiAutomator2, clearSystemFiles: false, deviceName: TestDevice-1, noReset: true, platformName: android, platformVersion: 7.1.1, udid: ZH33D2543D}, deviceApiLevel: 25, deviceManufacturer: motorola, deviceModel: Moto E (4) Plus, deviceName: ZH33D2543D, deviceScreenDensity: 320, deviceScreenSize: 720x1280, deviceUDID: ZH33D2543D, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: false, networkConnectionEnabled: true, noReset: true, pixelRatio: 2, platform: LINUX, platformName: Android, platformVersion: 7.1.1, statBarHeight: 48, takesScreenshot: true, udid: ZH33D2543D, viewportRect: {height: 1136, left: 0, top: 48, width: 720}, warnings: {}, webStorageEnabled: false}
Session ID: 9b91b01c-08bd-4b7a-a65e-4e09e5a7fcf5
*** Element info: {Using=id, value=login}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:239)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:41)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:323)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElement(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:61)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElement(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.findElement(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementById(RemoteWebDriver.java:372)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElementById(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:69)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElementById(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.findElementById(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ById.findElement(By.java:188)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:315)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElement(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:57)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElement(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.findElement(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$7.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:205)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$7.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:201)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$22.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:641)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$22.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:638)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:249)
    at com.odealMobile.PaymentFlow.launchedOdealApp(PaymentFlow.java:44)
    at ✽.Given odeal app is launched(src/test/resources/features/Android/Payment.feature:7)


===============================================
Suite
Total tests run: 1, Passes: 0, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Actually i see opened app on the mobile device but my case does not run. I want to emphasize app opens two times. Firstly app opens and the home page is appeared and then it is closed. Then app  opens second time and no case are running.

Mobile device that i've used for my test : Motorola Moto E(4) Plus , 7.1.1
Appium version 1.15.1

My Desired Capability Details :

```
 //Screen Classes Initialization
    public void setupCucumber () throws MalformedURLException {
         DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
         cap.setCapability("deviceName", "TestDevice-1");
         cap.setCapability("automationName", "UiAutomator2");
         cap.setCapability("udid", "ZH33D2543D");
         cap.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
         cap.setCapability("platformVersion", "7.1.1");
         cap.setCapability("noReset", "true");
         //cap.setCapability("fullReset", "false");
         cap.setCapability("clearSystemFiles", "false");
         cap.setCapability("appPackage", "com.telera.merchant.stage.debug");
         cap.setCapability("appActivity", "com.telera.merchant.splash.SplashActivity");
         cap.setCapability("app", "/Users/busekaya/Desktop/app-stage-debug.apk");
         //cap.setCapability("autoAcceptAlerts", true);
         //cap.setCapability("path", "/Users/busekaya/Desktop/app-stage-debug.apk");
         driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap); //"http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub\"
         driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(200, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
         wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 200);
    }
```

Cucumber feature file ;

```
Feature: [1] All Scenarios About Payment    

  @buse2  
  Scenario: [1.0] Check Incoming Payment Types
     Given app is launched
     When  user log in successfully
     And Clicks on New Payment button
     And Enter Price to Opened Page
     And Clicks on the Get Paid button
     Then All Payment Types will be Appeared
```

Comment: Appium version?

Comment: appium version 1.15.1

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this might apply but I was running into the same issue, app was installed but Appium was terminating my sessions immediately saying it was

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while connecting UiAutomation

In my case, inspired on @DebanjanB answer, I reinstalled Appium's UiAutomator2 package and it worked perfectly right after

I ran this:

```
yarn add appium-uiautomator2-driver
```

If you're using npm, run this instead

```
npm i appium-uiautomator2-driver
```

Answer (score -1):

This error message...

```
[31morg.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: A session is either terminated or not started
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'admins-Mac-mini.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:14b1:249d:6e8e:379f%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.15.3', java.version: '1.8.0_231'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Capabilities {app: /Users/busekaya/Desktop/app..., appActivity: com.telera.merchant.splash...., appPackage: com.telera.merchant.stage.d..., automationName: UiAutomator2, clearSystemFiles: false, databaseEnabled: false, desired: {app: /Users/busekaya/Desktop/app..., appActivity: com.telera.merchant.splash...., appPackage: com.telera.merchant.stage.d..., automationName: UiAutomator2, clearSystemFiles: false, deviceName: TestDevice-1, noReset: true, platformName: android, platformVersion: 7.1.1, udid: ZH33D2543D}, deviceApiLevel: 25, deviceManufacturer: motorola, deviceModel: Moto E (4) Plus, deviceName: ZH33D2543D, deviceScreenDensity: 320, deviceScreenSize: 720x1280, deviceUDID: ZH33D2543D, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: false, networkConnectionEnabled: true, noReset: true, pixelRatio: 2, platform: LINUX, platformName: Android, platformVersion: 7.1.1, statBarHeight: 48, takesScreenshot: true, udid: ZH33D2543D, viewportRect: {height: 1136, left: 0, top: 48, width: 720}, warnings: {}, webStorageEnabled: false}
Session ID: 9b91b01c-08bd-4b7a-a65e-4e09e5a7fcf5
*** Element info: {Using=id, value=login}
```

...implies that the *AndroidDriver* was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* through *UiAutomator2*.

---

Some more information from the server-side logs (Appium logs) would have helped us to analyze the issue in a better way. However, as you are using **Appium v1.15.1**, as per the discussion [Error: The instrumentation process cannot be initialized](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/12607) this issue is observed with [appium](/questions/tagged/appium) *v1.11* and above, where as in version *v1.10.1* there is no such issue. Presumably the server-side logs (Appium logs) would contain more details in the form of *logs messages* related to **UiAutomator2** in similar lines:

```
[UiAutomator2] 'skipServerInstallation' is set. Attempting to use UIAutomator2 server from the device
[UiAutomator2] Waiting up to 60000ms for UiAutomator2 to be online...
[debug] [ADB] Creating ADB subprocess with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","am","instrument","-w","io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"]
[debug] [Instrumentation] android.util.AndroidException: INSTRUMENTATION_FAILED: io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
```

The possible reason is, the *UiAutomator2* is not installed on the device or may be the server installation is disabled explicitly.

---

### Solution

A easier solution would have been to upgrade/downgrade *UIAutomator2* inside Appium but you can't do that since *UIAutomator2* has dependency on other modules.

So, the solution is to downgrade the whole Appium package. As an alternative, you can change the emulator/simulator on the device you are running your tests as well. At times uninstalling the `Appium Settings` app from the device and restarting the *Appium* process aslo solves the issue.